# can you add an alexa skill to more than one lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I want to add more functionality to my current alexa skill, would i need to make another lambda function for the functionality id like to add or could i add it to my current function?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest publishing a current version of your function. Create two aliases one as Prod and Dev. Point the prod alias to published version. Point your dev to $latest version.

On developer console paste the arn url of dev alias in the endpoint. Make changes to $latest aws lambda function. This way you dont have to create two functions.

More on aliases and versioning [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html).